# How to copy selective image files from one folder to another using PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

I am unable to copy selective images from one folder to another.

Source_folder: Has 33k image file with names like ISIC_4517738,ISIC_2342769,ISIC_8872158,ISIC_5247560
ISIC_4523382.........

I want to copy only like let say 100 images with names ISIC_8672524,ISIC_1255336,ISIC_7800750,ISIC_3023646..... .
from Source folder to destination folder.

Can u help to maybe modify this code or any other easy approach.... Thanks in adavnce

```
import glob
import shutil
import os

src_dir = "your/source/dir"
dst_dir = "your/destination/dir"
for jpgfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "*.jpg")):
    shutil.copy(jpgfile, dst_dir)
```

Comment: use `os.listdir("folderpath")[:100]` to get the first 100 images and copy them to destination.

Comment: Please clarify what files you want to get. We can't infer it from your question.